# php modulo division by zero

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on an table layout.
If there is x ammount of rows it will then go to the next row.

However de modulo is giving me an error when its trying to divide it by 0.

This is normal i know.

How can i check if the data is NULL and then returns next row with no data in it.

```
$j=0;
foreach($PortalName as $data1){
  $countQuery = $db->query('SELECT *, COUNT(gold_sended) as total_runs FROM gold_sended WHERE gold_sended.user_id = "'.$data1[1].'" AND (gold_swap_id = "'.$db->real_escape_string($_GET['a']).'") AND (week = "29") ORDER BY date DESC');
  while($count = $countQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($j % $count['total_runs'] == 0 && $j > 0) {
      echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.number_format($count['gold_sended']).'</td><td bgcolor="Yellow"><font color="#000">'.$count['date'].'</font></td>';
    $j++;
  }
}
```

total_runs is for some player 0 because they haven't sended anything.
So if an player has not sent anything it must output an empty row.
If there is data. proceed with the rest of the code.

Any tips will be appriciated.

Edit:
Almost done but they layout is still not correct.
the code is now as follow

```
<?php
                    $j=0;
                    foreach($PortalName as $data)
                    {
                        if($data[2] == 0) { echo '</tr><td>&nbsp;</td><tr>'; } else if($data[2] > 0 && $j % $data[2] == 0 && $j > 0) { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
                        $countQuery = $db->query('SELECT * FROM gold_sended WHERE gold_sended.user_id = "'.$data[1].'" AND (gold_swap_id = "'.$db->real_escape_string($_GET['a']).'") AND (week = "29") ORDER BY date DESC');
                        while($count = $countQuery->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            echo '<td>'.number_format($count['gold_sended']).'</td><td bgcolor="Yellow"><font color="#000">'.$data[4].'</font></td>';
                        }
                        $j++;
                    }
                    ?>
```

This will generate the following output
[image]

However this is not correct.
Because Fred has only sended 150000000

The rest is for the next member.

Ok its solved now.
Changed this row

```
if($data[2] == 0) { echo '</tr><td>&nbsp;</td><tr>'; } else if($data[2] > 0 && $j % $data[2] == 0 && $j > 0) { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
```

to

```
if($data[2] == 0) { echo '</tr><td>&nbsp;</td><tr>'; } else if($data[2] > 0 && $j % $data[2] == 0 && $j > 0) { echo '</tr><tr>'; } else { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
```

Its producing now the correct layout.

Thank you all

Comment: `if ($count['total_runs'] == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

With in your if statement add a validation that total_run not == 0

```
if($count['total_runs']1>0 && $j % $count['total_runs'] == 0 && $j > 0) {
```

Comment: So everything is ok now ? If yes I will be happy for you if not explain the current problem. if I help you and everything is ok please rate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use "continue" statement to do this

```
if($count['total_runs'] == null ||  $count['total_runs'] == 0) {
       continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if `total_runs` is empty and use `continue` keyword to skip to the next item of your loop

```
if(empty($count['total_runs'])) {
      // put your table row ending code here

       continue;
}
```